# Using copy_constructible in Boost.TypeErasure

Tags: c++, boost, type-erasure

I'm making a simple example using the new Boost.TypeErasure library. I have a simple class hierarchy (your standard textbook OO example):

```
class Employee {
public:
    std::string name() { return name_; }
    std::string name_;
};

class Developer : public Employee {
public:
    explicit Developer(const std::string& name) : Employee{name} {}
    double salary() { return 100; }
};

class Manager : public Employee {
public:
    explicit Manager(const std::string& name) : Employee{name} {}
    double salary() { return 200; }
};
```

And I wanted to put these into an `any` that requires methods for `salary()` and `name()`. So, based on the documentation, I did this:

```
BOOST_TYPE_ERASURE_MEMBER((has_salary), salary, 0);
BOOST_TYPE_ERASURE_MEMBER((has_name), name, 0);

typedef any<mpl::vector<
    copy_constructible<>, // why?
    has_salary<double()>,
    has_name<std::string()>
    >
> SalariedPerson;
```

Which lets me do:

```
SalariedPerson sp = Manager{"John Doe"};
cout << sp.name() << " has a salary of " << sp.salary() << endl;
```

I do not understand why I need `copy_constructible<>` in there. With it, everything compiles and runs as expected. Without it, I get this compile error (pointing to the construction of `sp`):

```
error: invalid static_cast from type ‘const boost::type_erasure::detail::vtable_storage<boost::type_erasure::detail::vtable_adapter<has_salary<double(), boost::type_erasure::_self>, double(boost::type_erasure::detail::storage&)>, boost::type_erasure::detail::vtable_adapter<has_name<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >(), boost::type_erasure::_self>, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >(boost::type_erasure::detail::storage&)> >* const’ to type ‘const boost::type_erasure::detail::vtable_entry<boost::type_erasure::destructible<boost::type_erasure::_self> >*’
```

Why the error, I'm not trying to copy construct anything, and the examples don't seem to use it.

Comment: Doesn't the temporary Manager need to be copied into the SalariedPerson, requiring a copy constructor?

Comment: Why copied and not moved? I need that use case.